# Spring Boot application failed to start on Java 1.8 version

Tags: java, spring-boot, tomcat

```
2021-01-31 16:47:19.244  INFO 2436 --- [           main] technicalblog.technicalblog              : Starting technicalblog on DESKTOP-IIPG7TQ with PID 2436 (C:\Users\Gajanan\IdeaProjects\webapplication\target\classes started by Gajanan in C:\Users\Gajanan\IdeaProjects\webapplication)
2021-01-31 16:47:19.249  INFO 2436 --- [           main] technicalblog.technicalblog              : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2021-01-31 16:47:19.334  INFO 2436 --- [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.AnnotationConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext@4c6e276e: startup date [Sun Jan 31 16:47:19 IST 2021]; root of context hierarchy
2021-01-31 16:47:20.795  INFO 2436 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration' of type [org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$b9db71a7] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2021-01-31 16:47:21.445  INFO 2436 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2021-01-31 16:47:21.475  INFO 2436 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2021-01-31 16:47:21.476  INFO 2436 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.5.34
2021-01-31 16:47:21.487  INFO 2436 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener   : The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: [C:\Users\Gajanan\.jdks\corretto-1.8.0_265\bin;C:\WINDOWS\Sun\Java\bin;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Intel\Shared Libraries\redist\intel64\compiler;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\Program Files\NVIDIA Corporation\NVIDIA NvDLISR;C:\Android;C:\Users\Gajanan\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin;C:\adb;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-14.0.2\bin;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-14.0.1\bin;C:\Users\Gajanan\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Users\Gajanan\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin;C:\Users\Gajanan\AppData\Local\GitHubDesktop\bin;.]
2021-01-31 16:47:21.623 ERROR 2436 --- [cat-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase   : A child container failed during start

java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Tomcat].StandardHost[localhost].TomcatEmbeddedContext[]]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122) [na:1.8.0_265]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:192) [na:1.8.0_265]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:942) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:872) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1420) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1410) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) [na:1.8.0_265]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [na:1.8.0_265]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [na:1.8.0_265]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_265]
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Tomcat].StandardHost[localhost].TomcatEmbeddedContext[]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:167) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
    ... 6 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.AbstractMethodError: org.apache.tomcat.util.descriptor.tld.TldRuleSet.getNamespaceURI()Ljava/lang/String;
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester.addRuleSet(Digester.java:1601) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.descriptor.DigesterFactory.newDigester(DigesterFactory.java:174) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.descriptor.tld.TldParser.<init>(TldParser.java:49) ~[tomcat-embed-jasper-9.0.41.jar:9.0.41]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.descriptor.tld.TldParser.<init>(TldParser.java:44) ~[tomcat-embed-jasper-9.0.41.jar:9.0.41]
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.<init>(TldScanner.java:84) ~[tomcat-embed-jasper-9.0.41.jar:9.0.41]
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JasperInitializer.newTldScanner(JasperInitializer.java:100) ~[tomcat-embed-jasper-9.0.41.jar:9.0.41]
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JasperInitializer.onStartup(JasperInitializer.java:81) ~[tomcat-embed-jasper-9.0.41.jar:9.0.41]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5245) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
    ... 6 common frames omitted

2021-01-31 16:47:21.624 ERROR 2436 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase   : A child container failed during start

java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Tomcat].StandardHost[localhost]]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122) ~[na:1.8.0_265]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:192) ~[na:1.8.0_265]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:942) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:262) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:422) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:793) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Tomcat.start(Tomcat.java:366) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.initialize(TomcatWebServer.java:107) [spring-boot-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.<init>(TomcatWebServer.java:86) [spring-boot-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatServletWebServerFactory.getTomcatWebServer(TomcatServletWebServerFactory.java:413) [spring-boot-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatServletWebServerFactory.getWebServer(TomcatServletWebServerFactory.java:174) [spring-boot-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.createWebServer(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:179) [spring-boot-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.onRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:152) [spring-boot-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:544) [spring-context-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:140) [spring-boot-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:780) [spring-boot-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:412) [spring-boot-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:333) [spring-boot-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1277) [spring-boot-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1265) [spring-boot-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
    at technicalblog.technicalblog.main(technicalblog.java:20) [classes/:na]
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Tomcat].StandardHost[localhost]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:167) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1420) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1410) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) ~[na:1.8.0_265]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) ~[na:1.8.0_265]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) ~[na:1.8.0_265]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) ~[na:1.8.0_265]
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:950) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:872) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
    ... 6 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Tomcat].StandardHost[localhost].TomcatEmbeddedContext[]]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122) ~[na:1.8.0_265]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:192) ~[na:1.8.0_265]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:942) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
    ... 8 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Tomcat].StandardHost[localhost].TomcatEmbeddedContext[]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:167) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
    ... 6 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.AbstractMethodError: org.apache.tomcat.util.descriptor.tld.TldRuleSet.getNamespaceURI()Ljava/lang/String;
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester.addRuleSet(Digester.java:1601) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.descriptor.DigesterFactory.newDigester(DigesterFactory.java:174) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.descriptor.tld.TldParser.<init>(TldParser.java:49) ~[tomcat-embed-jasper-9.0.41.jar:9.0.41]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.descriptor.tld.TldParser.<init>(TldParser.java:44) ~[tomcat-embed-jasper-9.0.41.jar:9.0.41]
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.<init>(TldScanner.java:84) ~[tomcat-embed-jasper-9.0.41.jar:9.0.41]
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JasperInitializer.newTldScanner(JasperInitializer.java:100) ~[tomcat-embed-jasper-9.0.41.jar:9.0.41]
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JasperInitializer.onStartup(JasperInitializer.java:81) ~[tomcat-embed-jasper-9.0.41.jar:9.0.41]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5245) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
    ... 6 common frames omitted

2021-01-31 16:47:21.624  INFO 2436 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
2021-01-31 16:47:21.625  WARN 2436 --- [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start web server; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.web.server.WebServerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat
2021-01-31 16:47:21.634  INFO 2436 --- [           main] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2021-01-31 16:47:21.637 ERROR 2436 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start web server; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.web.server.WebServerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.onRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:155) ~[spring-boot-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:544) ~[spring-context-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:140) ~[spring-boot-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:780) [spring-boot-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:412) [spring-boot-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:333) [spring-boot-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1277) [spring-boot-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1265) [spring-boot-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
    at technicalblog.technicalblog.main(technicalblog.java:20) [classes/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.boot.web.server.WebServerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.initialize(TomcatWebServer.java:126) ~[spring-boot-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.<init>(TomcatWebServer.java:86) ~[spring-boot-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatServletWebServerFactory.getTomcatWebServer(TomcatServletWebServerFactory.java:413) ~[spring-boot-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatServletWebServerFactory.getWebServer(TomcatServletWebServerFactory.java:174) ~[spring-boot-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.createWebServer(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:179) ~[spring-boot-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.onRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:152) ~[spring-boot-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
    ... 8 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardServer[-1]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:167) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Tomcat.start(Tomcat.java:366) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.initialize(TomcatWebServer.java:107) ~[spring-boot-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
    ... 13 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardService[Tomcat]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:167) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:793) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
    ... 15 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Tomcat]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:167) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:422) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
    ... 17 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:950) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:262) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
    ... 19 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Tomcat].StandardHost[localhost]]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122) ~[na:1.8.0_265]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:192) ~[na:1.8.0_265]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:942) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
    ... 21 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Tomcat].StandardHost[localhost]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:167) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1420) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1410) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) ~[na:1.8.0_265]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) ~[na:1.8.0_265]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) ~[na:1.8.0_265]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) ~[na:1.8.0_265]
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:950) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:872) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
    ... 6 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Tomcat].StandardHost[localhost].TomcatEmbeddedContext[]]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122) ~[na:1.8.0_265]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:192) ~[na:1.8.0_265]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:942) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
    ... 8 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Tomcat].StandardHost[localhost].TomcatEmbeddedContext[]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:167) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
    ... 6 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.AbstractMethodError: org.apache.tomcat.util.descriptor.tld.TldRuleSet.getNamespaceURI()Ljava/lang/String;
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester.addRuleSet(Digester.java:1601) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.descriptor.DigesterFactory.newDigester(DigesterFactory.java:174) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.descriptor.tld.TldParser.<init>(TldParser.java:49) ~[tomcat-embed-jasper-9.0.41.jar:9.0.41]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.descriptor.tld.TldParser.<init>(TldParser.java:44) ~[tomcat-embed-jasper-9.0.41.jar:9.0.41]
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.<init>(TldScanner.java:84) ~[tomcat-embed-jasper-9.0.41.jar:9.0.41]
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JasperInitializer.newTldScanner(JasperInitializer.java:100) ~[tomcat-embed-jasper-9.0.41.jar:9.0.41]
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JasperInitializer.onStartup(JasperInitializer.java:81) ~[tomcat-embed-jasper-9.0.41.jar:9.0.41]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5245) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
    ... 6 common frames omitted
```

Pom.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project
   xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0
   http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
   <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
   <groupId>org.upgrad</groupId>
   <artifactId>webapplication</artifactId>
   <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
   <parent>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <version>2.0.5.RELEASE</version>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
   </parent>
   <dependencies>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
         <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
         <version>2.4.1</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
         <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
         <version>2.4.1</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
         <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
         <version>42.2.2</version>
         <scope>runtime</scope>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
         <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
         <version>2.4.1</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.javassist</groupId>
         <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
         <version>3.23.1-GA</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
         <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
         <version>9.0.41</version>
      </dependency>
   </dependencies>
</project>
```

Comment: please provide related code and trace instead of pasting only trace

Comment: Please provide a code so that it's easy to look at your problem.

Comment: Remove all version tags from things like sprint-boot-start*, tomcat-embed.. etc. because all of those versions are handled by the spring boot parent.

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to mix jars from Tomcat 8.5.34 (the default version of Tomcat used by Spring Boot 2.0.5) and Tomcat 9.0.41. Rather than specifying a version when declaring the dependency on `tomcat-embed-jasper` you should allow Spring Boot's dependency management to control the version. You can do this by omitting the `<version>`:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
    <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
    <version>9.0.41</version>
</dependency>
```

Spring Boot's dependency management is available as you have used `spring-boot-starter-parent` as your project's parent:

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <version>2.0.5.RELEASE</version>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
</parent>
```

It's not directly related to you problem, but you should also remove the versions from your various `spring-boot-starter-…` dependencies. This will allow the version to be controlled by `spring-boot-starter-parent`.

If you want to use Spring Boot 2.4, you should change the version of the `<parent>` rather than overriding the versions of individual modules.

Comment: I removed all version tags and remain parent spring-boot-starter at 2.0.5.Release but still its not working.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be the issue with version mismatch between the jars in your dependencies. Please try to remove the version from starter web.  2.4.1